# Flutter split String by matched custom tags

Tags: flutter

I'm working on application in flutter and I need to split ad String containing custom tags. To understand I have a string like this

`String text = "You have disadvantage on checks against being &lt;LSTag Type="Status" Tooltip="RESTRAINED"&gt;Restrained&lt;/LSTag&gt;, but when you are restrained, you receive [1] (equal to level) bonus HP per turn."`

and the custom tag start with `&lt;LSTag` and end with `/LSTag&gt;` and I want to split the String to get a result like:

```
result = [
   "You have disadvantage on checks against being ",
   "&lt;LSTag Type="Status" Tooltip="RESTRAINED"&gt;Restrained&lt;/LSTag&gt;",
   ", but when you are restrained, you receive [1] (equal to level) bonus HP per turn.",
];
```

and other

```
String text = "When you are &lt;LSTag Type="Status" Tooltip="WET"&gt;Wet&lt;/LSTag&gt;, you gain &lt;LSTag Type="Status" Tooltip="FREEDOM_OF_MOVEMENT"&gt;Freedom of Movement&lt;/LSTag&gt;"
```

output:

```
result = [
   "When you are ",
   "&lt;LSTag Type="Status" Tooltip="WET"&gt;Wet&lt;/LSTag&gt;",
   ", you gain ",
   "&lt;LSTag Type="Status" Tooltip="FREEDOM_OF_MOVEMENT"&gt;Freedom of Movement&lt;/LSTag&gt;"
];
```

I'm going crazy to achieve this

```
String text = "When you are &lt;LSTag Type="Status" Tooltip="WET"&gt;Wet&lt;/LSTag&gt;, you gain &lt;LSTag Type="Status" Tooltip="FREEDOM_OF_MOVEMENT"&gt;Freedom of Movement&lt;/LSTag&gt;"
```

output:

```
result = [
   "When you are ",
   "&lt;LSTag Type="Status" Tooltip="WET"&gt;Wet&lt;/LSTag&gt;",
   ", you gain ",
   "&lt;LSTag Type="Status" Tooltip="FREEDOM_OF_MOVEMENT"&gt;Freedom of Movement&lt;/LSTag&gt;"
];
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can understand you want to split the string for custom text. The main issue is this custom text contains special characters.

To achieve this you need to create your own split function based of tab values & repeat this to test the case of multiple tags. Also you need to treat these text as string.

Try something like this.

```
void getSplit(String s, List<String> split){
  int startIndex = s.indexOf("&lt;LSTag");
  int endIndex = s.indexOf("&lt;/LSTag&gt;");

  if(startIndex > -1 && endIndex > -1){
    endIndex += 14;
    split.add(s.substring(0, startIndex).trim());
    split.add(s.substring(startIndex, endIndex).trim());

    getSplit(s.substring(endIndex, s.length), split);
  }
  else{
    split.add(s);
  }
}
```

Then call this function like this

```
List<String> split = [];
getSplit(text, split);
// here you can use the split collection to print
for(var s in split){
  print(s);
}
```

Hope this helps